# Android app - Text being cut off on log in screen

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

App version: 1.0.20

Phone: Huawei Ascend G510 (running Android 4.1.1)

On the log in screen some, of the text gets cut off because the text is longer than the button.

[image: Log in screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed as of version 0.1.21, thanks!

Comment: The problem has happened with the sign up screen now.